# How to insert data in custom table using REST API in Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I Have custom table name like test_table and it contains fields like name, number and city.

I want to insert data using Magento 2 REST API.

Please Let me know if you have any idea?

Comment: Hi Rajan please check the answer which i have posted might be which is very useful and simple steps if u have any query please commit me thanks @Rajan

Comment: Hi Rajan let me know whether u tried my answer? If u have any questions comment me thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1:-** Create a module Stackexchange_Test using silk software module creator [Click here to create a module](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php)

**Step2 :-** create a install script using below script in the below path **app/code/Stackexchange/Test/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Test\Setup;
class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        //START: install stuff
        //END:   install stuff

    //START table setup
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('test_table')
    )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [ 'identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true, 'unsigned' => true, ],
            'Entity ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [ 'nullable' => false, ],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'number',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [ 'nullable' => false, ],
            'Number'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'city',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [ 'nullable' => false, ],
            'City'
        );
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
//END   table setup
$installer->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

Now steps to create a api

**Step 3:** **app/code/Stackexchange/Test/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
 <route url="/V1/hello/test/" method="POST">
        <service class="Stackexchange\Test\Api\TestInterface" method="setData"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Step 4:** **app/code/Stackexchange/Test/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Stackexchange\Test\Api\TestInterface" type="Stackexchange\Test\Model\Test" />
</config>
```

**Step 5:** app/code/Stackexchange/Test/Api/TestInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Test\Api;

interface TestInterface
{

    /**
     * POST for test api
     * @param string[] $data
     * @return string
     */

  public function setData($data);

}
```

**Step 6: app/code/Stackexchange/Test/Model/Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Test\Model;
use Stackexchange\Test\Api\TestInterface;
class Test implements TestInterface
{


     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {   
        $id =  $data['id'];
        $name =$data['name'];
        $number =$data['number'];
        $city =$data['city'];
        //Customize the code as per your requirement.

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('test_table');

        $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (id, name, number, city) Values ('2','hello','50','Hyderabad')";     
        $connection->query($sql);       
        return 'successfully saved';
    }
}
```

**Step 7:-** While do the changes please use di compile and clear cache and page cache and deploy the same

**Step 8:** Please post the data using postman app as shown in the below screenshot.

**Note:** Header section  [{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]

[image: post men header section]

**Body section:-**

[image]

**Step 9:  check the data base table 'test_table'**

[image]

Comment: You are welcome @rajan thanks for giving the reply  happy coding

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nagaraju its working fine when updates the query in model file like below link

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-mysql-update-query-using-magento-2/

Comment: @NagarajuKasa  :  My API has  request data, from which some need to save in one and some in other tables. So how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

any one help to what i do in Test.php file

Comment: i cleare the problem using  $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (id, name, number, city) Values ('".$id."','".$name."','".$number."','".$city."')";  this line into Test.php lin 24